# Restoring default GUI QStyle on Windows 7 OS

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm writing a GUI application using Qt 4.7 on Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit. I'd like to let users change the GUI style from main menu. Several QStyles (QCDEStyle, QWindowsStyle, QCleanlooksStyle etc) can be selected from the menu and I'm using `QApplication::setStyle()` to set the new style.

I'd like to have an option to return back to the default style for Windows 7. By default style, what I mean is to use the style returned by `QApplication::style()` before any style is set explicitly using `QApplication::setStyle()`. Following is the attempt that will not work:

```
QStyle *default_style;

// During initialization of QMainWindow
default_style = QApplication::style();

// When default style is chosen from main menu
QApplication::setStyle(default_style);
```

The above will not work because `QApplication::setStyle()` takes ownership of the object and deletes previous `QStyle*`.

How can I change `QApplication` style to the default one? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of sourcediving, it turns out styles have their object names set to the style name, so you can say:

```
QString defaultStyle = this->style()->objectName();
```

and later

```
qApp->setStyle(defaultStyle);
```